# How to express in a simpler form of any matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Show that every $m \times n$ matrix $A$ over $F$ is equivalent to exactly one matrix of the form 
        $$B=\begin {pmatrix}
        I_{k \times k} & 0_{k \times (n-k)} \\
        0_{(m-k) \times k} & 0_{(m-k) \times (n-k)}  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

For some $k$. What my intuition is if we operate consecutive row column operation then I shall get my desired result i.e we want to find $Q$ s.t $B=QAQ^{-1}$. What I have problem is how do I express it? Is there some simpler form to express. Such that I am thinking $A$ will take the canonical basis elements $\{e_i | i=0,...,n\}$ of $F^n$ to some other elements of $F^n$ calculating the linearly independent spanning set of $\{Ae_i| i=0,..,n\}$, I can solve the problem in simpler way. Any idea ??

Comment: Your $B$ ($n\times n$) has not the same dimension as $A$ ($m\times n$).

Comment: Sorry a typo was there.

Comment: Given what you want to prove, I think you have the wrong equivalence in mind (as not all matrices are conjugate to such a matrix). It seems like what you are looking for is row equivalence.

Comment: Actually, reading it again, you just seem to have misunderstood what row operations do to the matrix. They multiply by an invertible matrix from the left, they do not conjugate by that matrix.

Comment: No I am saying consecutive row column operation, i.e premultiplying by $Q$ say the. postmultiplying by $Q^{-1}$

Comment: Usually the equivalence is only in terms of row operations (though this does not actually matter). But even if you also want column operations, you definitely do not want to multiply by $Q^{-1}$ from the right. For one thing, this is only defined if $B$ is square, and for another, this would mean performing the "same" column operations as you did row operations, and you will generaly not be able to get the form you want.